# How would I model a file system in dexie.js?

Tags: filesystems, indexeddb, dexie

I'm trying to create a virtual file system using dexie.js. Each file and directory would have at least 2 properties, id and name. In addition, files will have a blob property with the contents of the file. I do not know, however, whether to store a directory's children as a multi-valued index of the directory, or reference the parent as an index of the file. Which is the better choice?

My past SQL experience is telling me to go with the latter, but I do not know which case IndexedDB would handle better.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a hierarchial structure, something like the following:

```js
const db = new Dexie('filesystem');
db.version(1).stores({
  files: `
    [parentDir+name],
    parentDir`
});
```

By using the compound index [parentDir+name] the DB will ensure that no two items share the same path.

By indexing parentDir, you can list both direct children and recursive children only using the index.

Some examples:

```js
function createDir(parentDir, name) {
  // The following transaction will fail if
  // the combination parentDir+name already exists or
  // represents a file.
  return db.files.add({parentDir, name, type: "dir"});
}

function createFile(parentDir, filename, blob) {
  return db.transaction('rw', db.files, async ()=>{
    // Verify parentDir exists and is a directory:
    const dir = await db.files.get({
      parentDir: parentDir
    });
    if (!dir) throw new Error("Parent dir not found");
    if (dir.type !== 'dir') throw new Error("Parent is not a dir");
    await db.files.add({
      type: 'file',
      name: filename,
      parentDir,
      blob
    });
  });
}

/** List all files and folders within given diretory */
function listDirectory(dirPath) {
  return db.files
    .where({parentDir: dirPath})
    .toArray();
}

/** List all files and folders recursively within given diretory */
function listDirectoryRecursively(dirPath) {
  return db.files
    .where('parentDir')
    .startsWith(dirPath)
    .toArray();
}
```

Moving a file or directory will be fast as you can reach the whole subtree in a single query.

```js
function moveDirectory (oldParentDir, name, newParentDir) {
  return db.transaction('rw', db.files, async ()=>{

    // Move the directory itself:
    await db.files
      .where({parentDir: oldParentDir, name: name})
      .modify(item => item.parentDir = newDir);

    // Move all descendants:
    await db.files
      .where('parentDir')
      .startsWith(oldParentDir + "/" + name)
      .modify(item =>
        item.parentDir = newParentDir +
          item.parentDir.substr(oldParentDir.length) + // strip start
          "/" + item.name);
  });
}
```